# UITableViewCellAccessory Not Displayed on Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that I have created using the Interface Builder and a backing `UITableViewCell` subclass.  It's a simple cell, with a left-oriented label (as a name) and a right-oriented label (as the value).  I'm trying to display a disclosure indicator as the `UITableViewCellAccessory`, however no accessory is being displayed in the cell regardless of what I set.

My command to add it is simple enough within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

However, there is still no accessory displayed for the cell.  Is there something that I am missing?  Are accessories not displayable with custom `UITableViewCell` implementations?

Comment: Did you set your cell's re-use identifier and are you using it?

Comment: Yes.  The cell itself displays fine, except for the fact that the accessory is not present.  All of the other fields within the cell are presented as expected.

Comment: Check the tint of the cell or table, as this can sometimes have an affect on the accessory view.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if, in your custom cell, you implemented `layoutSubviews`, but neglected to call `super.layoutSubviews()`.